# Angular 5 - link to css file in node_module folder

Tags: css, angular

Currently I use this link in my angular 5 application in index.html:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/angular-calendar@0.23.6/css/angular-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I tried to change this link to:

```
<link href="./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but it does not work. Does anyone know what I have to do in order to get it work. Is even the folder **node_modules** packed with webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not do it in the index.html file

Make the changes in `angular-cli.json` file

```
  "styles": [
    "./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```